# Questions about uncountable logics?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

First of all, I would like to say that I've only recently started researching infinitary logics. I have read some segments of Barwise - related papers on the topic, and I could not find anything discussing 'uncountable logics' (logic's that allow formulae of uncountable length) within them. I am aware of basic properties of infinitary logics being that it fails to prove 'standard' compactness and completeness (a stronger definition is required for infinitary logics, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitary_logic), but what properties would be unique to an uncountable logic?

For specificity, this is the type of uncountable languages I am talking about (L<sub>ω<sub>2</sub></sub>,<sub>ω<sub>2</sub></sub>).

I have never seen the above logic referenced before so I also wonder is there something wrong with this type of logic that I haven't found out? Or that this something that just hasn't been studied enough yet?

Theoretically, since we can always have 'greater' logics that allow for longer formulae, I would like to present the idea of an 'ultimate logic'. The logic would look something like this (L<sub>Ω</sub>
,<sub>Ω</sub>) and would would be able to 'define' (in that the Godel coding's for such formulas are elements of the language) all possible formulae within logic (via allowing formulae of any length). My second question is that, could we one day hope to create an 'all defining' logic?

EDIT: The 'ultimate language' that allows for formulae of any ordinal length is  L∞,∞. But are there any known theories based off of this language?

Comment: The notion of $\cal L_{\infty,\infty}$, where we can take conjunctions and quantifiers over any ordinal length exists and is studied. Note that it is still a first-order infinitary logic, so it is not "ultimate" in any shape and form, since we can still add a lot of second-order quantifiers or even more than that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you that was exactly the answer I was hoping for my second question. I assume there is currently no known theory based off this language since said theory would be able to do things like defining all sets within V.

Comment: @SIJ I'm not sure what "there is currently no known theory based off this language" means, but certainly there is a lot known about classes of structures axiomatized by single $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\infty}$-sentences (*every* class of structures is axiomatized by an $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\infty}$-*theory* so that question isn't interesting). For example, the class of structures whose cardinality is a limit cardinal (in your fixed favorite language) is **not** such a class, and this gives a proof that $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\infty}$ is of incomparable strength to second-order logic.

Comment: In general, see [*Model-theoretic logics*](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/perspectives-in-logic/Model-Theoretic-Logics/toc/pl/1235417263). There's a lot known about large infinitary languages, and that text is a good starting point. (Beyond that you'll want to look at individual papers, e.g. Sy Friedman's [*Model theory of $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega_1}$*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0168007284900125?via%3Dihub).)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you for the information, I will read into that. By 'based off this language I mean is there a theory based off  L∞,∞ in a similar sense to how ZFC is 'based' off of  Lω,ω. Which I from my understanding, there isn't as it would be a theory (one with a known axiom set as of course you can do something like 'the set of all true statements in L∞,∞') far greater than ZFC in strength and would be quite known.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Does L∞,∞ allow arbitrarily long formulae in a given model? Or arbitrarily long with no specification of models? For example would ∞ = k, where k is the least inaccessible cardinal. So this language allows for formulae <k in length.